# Очищение командной строки

Tags: bat

Как сделать выполнение одной части кода, и в этот же момент очищать всю командную строку командой cls? (если что, 1-ю часть кода нужно выполнить 1 раз, а 2-ю часть выполнять бесконечное количество раз до определённого момента, одновременно с 1-ой частью)
Хочу найти способ без дополнительных инструментов и без vbs, если это, конечно, возможно.

Comment: Надо работать с потоками точно не знаю как но поищи что-то типо:"Многопоточность в bat файле"

Comment: Если нужно просто скрыть вывод первой команды, можно написать >> NUL. Например, dir >> NULL